# About a theorem of Mestre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

There is a theorem of Mestre witch states:
If $K$ is any field, let $p(x)  \in  k[x]$  is a monic polynomial with degree $2n$, then there exist polynomials $g(x)$ and $r(x)$ with:
1) $g(x)$ and $r(x)$ in $K[x]$
2) $\deg g(x)= n$  and $\deg r(x) \leq n-1$  
3) $ g^{2}(x)-r(x)=p(x)$

Can anybody give the exact proof with details. I have garikai campbell's thesis but I can't realize that.

Comment: You are using both $k$ and $K$ to denote the same field (I suppose) - it would be better to unify the notation.

Comment: Are you sure $K$ is arbitrary and not a field of characteristic not $2$? Anyway, your setup sounds like approximating a square root: finding a polynomial $g$ so that $\deg(g^2 - p) < \deg(p)/2$ (the condition $\deg(g) = n$ follows from the other properties you list) is saying $|g^2 - p|_{\infty} < \sqrt{|p|_{\infty}}$ where $|f|_{\infty} := 2^{\deg f}$ (or any number greater than $1$ as the base in place of $2$) is the "absolute value at infinity" on $K(x)$, with completion $K((1/x))$. Monic polynomials of even degree have a square root in $K((1/x))$. Use the continued fraction for $\sqrt{p}$?

Comment: What is the Mestre reference? While I am sure there could be a purely polynomial proof out there, from the viewpoint of continued fractions in $K((1/x))$ this type of result was known to people like Emil Artin in the early 20th century.

Comment: It doesn't work in characteristic $2$.  Thus $p = x^2+x$ would not work, because the $x^1$ coefficient of $g^2$ would be $0$.

Comment: Following @Robert Israelcomment,  in char.2, the right condition is probably $g^2+g-r=p$, although I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 3):

Write $p(x)= x^{2n}+a_1x^{2n-1}+\ldots $. You are looking for a polynomial $g(x)=x^n+ b_1x^{n-1}+\ldots $ such that $\deg(p-g^2)<n$. Equating coefficients gives $\sum\limits_{i=0}^p b_{i}b_{p-i}= a_{p}$ for $1\leq p\leq n$. Taking $b_{0}=1$ we get $2b_{1}=a_{1}$, then $2b_{2}+b_{1}^2= a_2$, then $2b_{3}+2b_{1}b_{2}=a_3$, etc. If we assume $\operatorname{char}(K)\neq 2 $, this is a triangular system, the $p$-th equation gives (uniquely) $b_p$ once $b_1,\ldots ,b_{p-1}$ are known.